# How to prevent \include from changing the position of text in a minipage?

Tags: positioning, minipage, alignment, include

When I place some text in a minipage it is positioned exactly as I expect, at the very top of the minipage. When I move the text to a separate .tex file and use the \include command it messes up the positioning by placing the text much lower than I would like to.

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

  \begin{minipage}[c][147mm][t]{104mm}

    hello world

  \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Now if you replace `hello world` with `\include{Cover_Text}` and place `hello world` in `Cover_Text.tex` it changes the position.

I use the `pdflatex` command and my version is as follows:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)
kpathsea version 6.3.2
```

Comment: you should never use \include inside a minipage it always starts a new page use \input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never use `\include` inside a minipage; it always starts a new page. Use `\input`.